# Tensorflow Restore Model and Predict

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a Tensorflow model and saved the output layer's tensor. When restoring, I restored the output layer's tensor and tried predicting with it but got an error saying I never assigned to a placeholder. My code is below, please assist.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
model_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_save_folder + '/my-model.meta')
model_saver.restore(sess, model_save_folder + '/my-model')
x = tf.placeholder('float')
output = tf.get_collection("output")[0] #output will be the tensor for model's last layer
print("Model restored.")
print('Initialized')
#print(sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('w_conv1:0')))

#collect list of preprocessed data on submission set
inputData = []
with open('stage1_sample_submission.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    num = 0

    for row in reader:
        if num > 0:
            patient = row[0]
            #print(patient)
            inputData.append(process_data(patient, img_px_size=IMG_SIZE_PX, hm_slices=SLICE_COUNT))
        num += 1

#prediction!
prediction = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: inputData})
print(prediction)
```

Comment: I think you need to restore the placeholder the same way.  x = tf.get_collection("placeholder")[0]  replace placeholder with whatever it's name is in the original graph.

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: I'll just post it as answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to restore the placeholder the same way.

```
x = tf.get_collection("placeholder")[0]
```

replace placeholder with whatever it's name is in the original graph

Comment: What does the `[0]` at the end stands for?

Comment: Honestly this question is over a year old at this point and the API has probably changed since this answer.  Back then it used to be that get collection would return a list of at least the weights themselves, and the variable names and scopes.  The [0] selects for the weights so you can feed into that directly.  I would refer to whatever the documentation says about get_collection to see what they currently return.